# Is there any Selenium-like software for executables?

Tags: automation, selenium

I have some app I want to test i.e. it has a window opening up and I want to press some of the buttons and fill in some text boxes, and I need to do the same process multiple times.

I heard about selenium but it seems it only works on web-based apps, whereas my program is an executable program (and quite a heavy one while at it).  Is there something similar to this, a module to be added to selenium or a library for python/Matlab/C?

I’d appreciate any help with this.

Comment: What OS/windowing system?

Comment: Oh, right. Using windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Windows user, but I'd start at [Comparison of GUI testing tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_GUI_testing_tools), looking for those supporting Windows for both **testing** and **tested** system.

Answer (score 0):

SikuliX may fit your needs:

"SikuliX automates anything you see on the screen of your desktop computer running Windows, Mac or some Linux/Unix. It uses image recognition powered by OpenCV to identify GUI components and can act on them with mouse and keyboard actions. This is handy in cases when there is no easy access to a GUI's internals or the source code of the application or web page you want to act on"

https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX1

Answer (score 0):

At the other end of sikulli is [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/), it supports record play and interaction by object ID'S.

As a side note testing through the GUI is not really efficient, scalable or reliabile, consider testing "under the GUI" if possible and leave only the most necessary things to it.

Answer (score 0):

For MATLAB you can use the [app testing framework](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/app-testing-framework.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav), but this is intended for interacting with MATLAB uifigures only. If thats what you are doing then this framework should enable that workflow.